# Membership.GetUser() fails when called from an HttpModule

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm calling `Membership.GetUser()` from inside `Application_Error()` method in Global.asax file in an ASP.NET application in order to write down some log information.

However, it seems to fail if an error happens inside an HttpModule.  Is it normal?  Isn't Membership ready while executing HttpModules in ASP.NET?  Am I doing something wrong?

It throws an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception (at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetCurrentUserName(), at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser()).

Comment: Can you be more specific? Does it throw an error or simply return null?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It throws an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception (at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetCurrentUserName(), at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser())

Comment: A HttpRequest goes through the stacks of HttpModules before an HttpHandler takes over. MembershipProvider is one of those modules. I'm assuming you are able to "GetUser" from the webform or handler. aAcessing the MembershipProvider on the otherhand might not be possible (my guess). Could be a HtpModule configuration issue in the web.config though. Meanwhile User.Identity.Name seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session doesn't exist yet, where membership stores its information.  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie sets a cookie but that cookie is read up.

I would look at two events in your Global.asax.cs (or whatever class derives from HttpApplication)

- AuthenticateRequest
- AcquireRequestState

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HttpApplication.User from inside Global's Application_Error.
eg:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Here's one I use:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Exception lastError = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        if (lastError is HttpException && ((HttpException)lastError).GetHttpCode() == 404)
            return;

        if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            lastError.Data.Add("Referrer", Request.UrlReferrer);
        if (Request.RawUrl != null)
            lastError.Data.Add("Page", Request.RawUrl);
        if (Request.UserHostAddress != null)
            lastError.Data.Add("Client IP", Request.UserHostAddress);
        if (Request.UserAgent != null)
            lastError.Data.Add("UserAgent", Request.UserAgent);
        if (User != null && User.Identity != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Identity.Name))
            lastError.Data.Add("User", User.Identity.Name);

        Log.Error("Application_Error trapped at Global.asax", lastError);
    }
    // ReSharper disable EmptyGeneralCatchClause
    catch { } // Intentionally empty catch clause as this is the catchall exception handler. If it fails, the sky has fallen.
    // ReSharper restore EmptyGeneralCatchClause
}
```